# android digital clock update every 5 seconds

Tags: android, textview, clock, digital

the idea is to display the current system time in a box on top of the front screen, in a digital format like hour:minute:seconds. It needs to be continuously updated. However, if you update the seconds every 1 sec, it might run the system down.therefore, I want the user to be able to choose the update rate (every 1 sec, 5 sec, or 10sec). The question is: how i can update an textview every 5 sec?
we write this code:

```
package com.example.software;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Time dtNow = new Time();
        dtNow.setToNow();
        int hours;
        int minutes;
        int second;
        int i=100;
        int j=0;
        TextView txt =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_view);

        while(i>0){

            hours = dtNow.hour;
            minutes= dtNow.minute;
            second = dtNow.second;
            txt.setText(hours+":"+minutes+":"+second);
        try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
        }



        }

    }


}
```

I update this code as :

```
package com.example.softwareproject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     Time dtNow = new Time();

     int hours;
     int minutes;
     int second;
     int i=100;
     int j=0;


     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         display();
    }

    public void display(){

        new Thread(new Runnable(){

            public void run() {

            while(i>0){
                    TextView txt =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_view);
                    dtNow.setToNow();
                    hours = dtNow.hour;
                    minutes= dtNow.minute;
                    second = dtNow.second;
                    txt.setText(hours+":"+minutes+":"+second);


                        try{
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                            }
                        catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                 }
        }).start();

    }

}
```

but i still have this error :

```
[2012-12-14 03:54:25 - SoftwareProject] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.softwareproject/.MainActivity }
[2012-12-14 03:54:25 - SoftwareProject] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

and the application stopped.

Comment: When you do this, your app will never leave the onCreate loop. You should create an asyntread or runnable and place the while loop in there.

Comment: Dear dmaij, i did what you said, and the application was run, but it displayed the time and after 5 second when it updates the time an error occurs and stopped the application(Unfortunately, Software project has stopped), but i don't know why :(, do you have any idea?.

Comment: and this is the message that's appears in console window: "[2012-12-14 03:54:25 - SoftwareProject] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.softwareproject/.MainActivity }
[2012-12-14 03:54:25 - SoftwareProject] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front"

Comment: @HusseinA.Hammoud, this message generally appears, when your application is already running and you try to rerun it. Try running your application after clearing data and force stop

Comment: Dear Shreya Shah, I rerun the application and the error in Console window was disappears, but it still stopped after 5 seconds and gives "Unfortunately, Software project has stopped" dialog.

Comment: Does it start at all when the call to 'display' is commented out?